# Defining the ordering relations between sisters in a graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graph-theory

Given a tree (a graph), I would like to define ordering relations between sister nodes. Is there such a structure? do I just add a set of ordering relations?

I know that an ordered graph defines an ordering relations for connected nodes. This is not what I am interested in.

For example, given the following tree:

```
      A
     / \
    B   C
   / \ / \
  D  E F  G
```

I want to define that there is an ordering relation between B and C (B comes first than C), between D and E, and between F and G. My guess is that I could just define a set of ordered pairs $O=\{(B,C),(D,E),(F,G)\}$ to express this (I do not want to define the order by the labels, labels are arbitrary, and the three might be non binary). But I do not know whether this is the right way to do it, or whether there already is some type of graph that does this.

I do not need an algorithm to find the order. I need to define the structure and say: structures of this kind are defined as directed trees, where sister nodes are ordered with respect to each other.

Comment: Yes, I saw that definition. Maybe I was unclear? In the definition of an ordered graph (if I understood it correctly) nodes are ordered with respect to other nodes they are connected to. I do not want this. I want a structure that is like a tree, but there is an ordering relation between sister nodes. I do not know whether there is such a thing in graph theory.

Comment: The phrase "breadth first search" comes to mind.

Comment: I have modified the question, maybe it is more clear now...?

Comment: I have tried again. I understand that in normal graphs there is no reason to prefer $(B,C)$ over $(C,B)$, but I have structures that do need to be ordered. Labels are arbitrary, the tree can be non binary. I do not need an algorithm for assigning the order, I need a structure that represents that order.

Comment: If you want there to be an order relation between any two pairs of elements, then what you want is just a list (or a "chain" or a "totally ordered set"; these are all synonyms). If you want there to be *only* order relations between siblings then you want a disjoint union of chains.

Comment: Please have a look at the [polytree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_graph), a directed graph whose underlying undirected graph is a tree, and at an [arborescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory)), a directed *rooted* tree.  As far as a structure that represents an ordering among sibling nodes, there seems to me little reason not to used a total ordering of nodes (ordered graph) which would be defined by [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) that prioritizes the siblings according to whatever order you wish to impose.

Comment: @EricStucky Could you post it as an answer to the question so I can mark the question as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want there to be an order relation between any two pairs of elements, then what you want is just a list (or a "chain" or a "totally ordered set"; these are all synonyms).

If you want there to be *only* order relations between siblings then you want a post which is a disjoint union of chains.